# Dark pictures in ImageViewer and Firefox

Tags: 14.04, firefox, image-viewers

I noticed that pictures viewed in Image Viewer are a lot darker than they should be, while if I open the same picture in Shotwell Photo Viewer, then the brightness of the pictures is ok. The same happens to some pictures in Firefox - I noticed that it happens to pictures which I upload with Firefox. If I open the same uploaded pictures in Chrome, then the brightness is ok.

[image: comparison of image in Shotwell Photo Viewer and Image Viewer]

If I run `sudo lshw -c video` I get:

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GT216M [GeForce GT 330M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:e2000000-e2ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:e3000000-e307ffff
```

I use:

- Sony VAIO VPCF11
- Ubuntu 14.04
- Firefox 34.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to **System Settings > Device Colour Profiles** and select your display, then click the <kbd>Add profile</kbd> button and change the display profile to **D65**.

[image: Device Colour Profiles]

Comment: Could you please clarify your answer? Where is `configuration > color > add profile` and how to you get to it? From my understanding it sounds like the Device Colour Profiles in System Settings but I can't be sure from your answer as it stands.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding i'm using ubuntu 14.04, go to System Settings in the hardware section select "color" and then the button "add profile" at the bottom of the window, now choose the profile "Test profile: D65" then "add".

Comment: On my machines running Gnome I just set it to be off - they may be a similar option in Unity's version.

Comment: This works. By the way, why D65? is it the most suitable for the monitor standard or something?